# Consequences of higher voltage supplied to BLDC motor?

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

What happens to a brush-less DC motor if I supply a voltage about 1.25 times greater than the rated voltage?

Comment: What do you think "rated voltage" means?

Comment: You can find the maximum voltage your motor can work at by gradually increasing the voltage until it catches fire, then back off a bit. Whether that happens at +25% rated voltage depends on your particular motor.

Comment: Short term it MAY work OK. Longer term most motors will die. Cores saturate, wire ohmically heats, ...

Comment: Are you talking about the DC bus voltage or the effective voltage actually applied by the motor controller?

Comment: Eventually your coils will burn enamel, a short circuit will happen and the radius of Ka-Boom will depend on how many amps flow through the short circuit. Also the bushes / bearings will give up adding more friction eventually giving off more heat. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The effect of 125% of rated voltage applied to a brushless DC  (BLDC) motor depends on whether you mean voltage supplied to the electronic speed controller (ESC) or to an individual motor coil.

Check the ESC specifications. If 125% of rated voltage is above the rated tolerance, the ESC may experience component failures. The ESC would likely protect the motor from damage. If 125% of rated voltage is within tolerance, the ESC should prevent the motor from experiencing any effect.

With respect to the voltage applied to the motor coils, it depends on the volt-seconds per pulse or volt-seconds for a series of pulses with the same polarity. If the volt-seconds are too high, the motor core will saturate and the current will increase. That would tend to overheat the motor, but the mechanical load on the motor would also need to be considered. If the net effect is enough to overheat the motor, the duration of the overheating condition and other heating and cooling factors would need to be considered. Operation at an excessive temperature will shorten the life of the motor.

Answer (score 0):

If the loaded. voltage drops 25% from the no load voltage, you are ok.

Reliability failure rates double increase with each 10'C rise.
Design or quality issues can accelerate much faster.

No information has been offered to view any other design issues.

WIth the assumption that PWM is used for speed control, you would not want to exceed rated power dissipation and thus use less than 80% PWM if the voltage does exceed Vmax for the motor.

Comment: I wouldn't generally say "you are OK", because OP might very well stressing thermal dissibation capabilities of switching components, so that the thing might stop working on a warmer day, or catch fire if used for a couple of hours